# How can I change bluetooth role in android? (master to slave)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In the project I am working on now, it is necessary to change Bluetooth (in Android phone) from master to slave.
How can I make this possible?

Let me know if you know how to switch from master to slave!

I tried nRF app but I don't know how to do it exactly.
I can't find any possible way about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about Bluetooth Low Energy (since you mention nRF app), you cannot just switch from master to slave. Your entire code has to be written as a master (in your case this is probably a central with a GATT client) or a slave (in your case this is probably a peripheral with a GATT server). Have a look at the links below for more information:-

Android BLE central (GATT client) implementation

- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/)
- [Making Android BLE work](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02)
- [Android BLE central example](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection/tree/main/ESP32/BLEProofCentral)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy on Android](https://www.stkent.com/2017/09/18/ble-on-android.html)

Android BLE peripheral (GATT server) implementation

- [How to advertise Android as a BLE peripheral](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426)
- [Android BLE peripheral example](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection/tree/main/Android/BLEProofPeripheral)
- [Bluetooth GATT server example](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver)
- [Using a GATT server](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/30768/using-a-gatt-server)

Generic BLE information

- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer)
- [Getting started with BLE](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Introduction to BLE GATT](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt)